# What is the grammatical name for "deserve should [verb]"

Tags: grammar

> So only complex commands **deserve | should use | merit** command helper functions.

Is the highlighted word (any one of the three) the verb in this sentence?  Is it a form of Catenative Verb? Can Catenative Verb use auxiliary Verbs?  Or is it some kind of Inversion?

Comment: ***should*** here is an ***auxiliary*** verb, but ***deserve, use,*** and ***merit*** are all just (main) verbs used ***transitively*** (you *deserve / use / merit **something***).

Comment: For my money, ***He deserves to die*** is an example of a "catenative" verb usage, but ***He deserves a good thrashing*** is just a simple transitive verb usage.

Comment: So is this just a typo? It's taken from http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/html/primercommand.html

Comment: Who said anything about a typo? All I'm saying is your cited text definitely isn't a *typical* example of a "catenative" verb, because that's normally where one verb form modifies another verb form, as in *He **likes watching** movies*. But your example is structurally equivalent to *He **likes movies*** - just an ordinary transitive verb usage *(**likes**)* followed by an "object" *(**movies**)*. But yes - if it wasn't already obvious, there should be some kind of "divider" (maybe a slash **/** or vertical bar **|**) in the written version. Which is irrelevant to ***real*** (spoken) language.

Comment: In fact, it wasn't obvious for me that the sentence have two verbs.  It's just "/" or "or" is missing from the sentence. Would you mind to add it as your answer so that I can check it as accepted answer?  Plus, I guess we need to fix the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is either deserve or should, so far as I understand your original statement.

> So only complex commands deserve command helper functions

or

> So only complex commands should use command helper functions

In this case, however, you *must* use the *second example* because deserve implies the complex commands have agency. Inanimate objects in English do not usually have agency in this way.

So whilst in Japanese we might say ケーキが食べたい - that is, the cake is inducing (me) to eat it - this formation is not regular in English.

Where the subject of the sentence is inanimate, similarly you cannot use verbs which confer a greater deal of agency (as in the case of deserve).

My apologies. To answer what type of verb it is; should use is catenative as should and use are verbs and use is the [bare infinitive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs#Followed_by_a_bare_infinitive) of to use in this instance. Deserve is simply the verb.

Comment: Possibly "should deserve to use" which is grammatically correct although clumsy.